# MVC VB move a record to a new table when deleted

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, model-view-controller

I'm working with MVC (still fairly new to it.) Once a user deletes a record from table A, I want to simply move it to table B (a history of deleted records) with information such as who deleted it, their IP, timestamp it was deleted, etc.

What is the best way to record deletes?

I'm using VB.NET

Comment: Why don't you just add a 'deleted' column (and IP if you need other data) to table A to indicate deleted rows?

Comment: for this solution it will depend on the business rules, if you need to implement a soft delete, then yes, add a flag or use the a column called DeletedDate as a flag for example, but will also depend on the indexes (duplicates allowed?), and the number of rows affected, it can create problems if not managed correctly, it is safer to have it outside of the main table.

Answer (score 1):

this can be accomplished on the back end (database) you can simply select the deleted value and insert it on the history table, to obtain the user information you can get all that you need from  HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser ([HttpContext.Browser)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.browser(v=vs.110).aspx) on the request. 
I would recommend you to set a stored proc that inserts and then deletes the row in a transaction.

Other way to do this is to use a trigger, on delete use the deleted table to insert it to the history table, I would not recommend this approach as using triggers creates overhead, but if you cannot modify the existing code and you need it then this is the way to go.